# svg - change svg color with css and load external sprite

Tags: css, svg

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/yQe0otxwy6GEepITLnJD?p=preview

Simple questions, I'm trying to change the color of the svg in a svg sprite use css.

I've tried using fill and currentColor like explained here - https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Second quesiton is I can load the sprite when it's a local file but I can't seem to load it when it's external.
like in the second example that doesn't display.

```
    /* svg{
      color: yellow;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      fill: currentColor;
    } */

    svg{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }

    .svg{
      fill: yellow;
    }

    .star{
      fill: yellow;
    }

    h3 {
      color: blue;
    }
    svg {
      fill: currentColor;
    }
```

Comment: CSS in your html file cannot affect another file. You've found that out yourself though. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is how do I change the color of the svg using css

Comment: As Robert said, you can't. You would need to have different SVG sprites, or add the different colour variants to your sprite SVG.  The currentColor method works with "local" `<use>`, but only with Chrome. https://plnkr.co/edit/IpdBW31x6nDa2w7pTLxZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but your plunker works if you remove all the inline style fill references in your external svg file. It will then inherit the fill set in your CSS.